# can we start a new thread in foreachRDD in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to start a child-thread in foreachRDD.

My situation is:

the job is reading from a hdfs dir continuously, and every 100 batches, I want to launch a model training task (I will make a snapshot of the rdds at that time and start the training task. the training task takes a very long time(2 hours), and I don't want the training task influence reading new batch of data.

Is starting a new child thread a good solution? Could the child thread use SparkContext in the main thread and use the rdd in main thread?

Comment: Would the built-in async processing  work for you? : https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.AsyncRDDActions

Comment: wouldn't it be better to launch a spark batch job every 2 hours instead?

Comment: @maasg  because the data is pretty large, load them from disk will take 1 hour. I think it 's a waste of disk io, and will delay the task...

Comment: @JustinPihony thank you , but this rsync rdd action are too simple. I need to run model training in mllib...

Comment: @user2848932 How large is the data? Are you planning to keep it in memory for hours?

Comment: @maasg  yes, i 'll keep one month's data in memory, about several TBs(one month's old data + 100 batches new data). I don't want to load them every two hours...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to start a new thread in RDD operations.
To start a new job in every a hundred batch, you can add a BatchListner to count number of batches, and start a new job when number equals to 100.
[BatchListener Example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/scheduler/StreamingListener.html)